# Angular 4 nested components

Tags: angular, components, ngfor

Hope you are well. I am quite new in typeScript and angular 4 and I have faced with an issue. I want to use one component in another component. The data will be accessible through Http with get method and comes in array of object in parent component and I want to use ngFor to repeat child component based on receiving data from parent component.

Following code is child component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-card',
  templateUrl: './app-card.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app-card.component.css']
})
export class AppCardComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
```

here is my child component.html

```
<mat-card class="pt-3">
  <mat-card-header class="text-truncate pb-2">
    <img mat-card-avatar src="http://material.angular.io/assets/img/examples/shiba1.jpg">
    <mat-card-title class="mt-2">{{pro.name}}</mat-card-title>
  </mat-card-header>
</mat-card>
```

Parent component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FeaturedService } from "../services/featured.service";


@Component({
  selector: 'app-collection',
  templateUrl: './collection.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./collection.component.css']
})
export class CollectionComponent implements OnInit {

  cc;

  constructor(private featured: FeaturedService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.featured.getAll().subscribe(results => {
      this.cc= results
    });

  }

}
```

and finally parent html

```
<div class="row">
          <div class="col-12 text-center pt-4 mb-4">
            <h3>Featured</h3>
            <hr class="title-border" />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div *ngFor="let pro of cc" class="col-xl-6 p-md-1 p-lg-1 p-xl-2">
            <app-card></app-card>
          </div>
        </div>
```

I do appreciate if you can help me to sort this issue out.

Comment: did you verified that the `results` coming from Http is correct ?

Comment: yes. I logged the results and is fine.

Comment: so see my answer

Answer (score 1):

use `@Input` to pass the `pro` from the parent to child

in the child component :

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-card',
  templateUrl: './app-card.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app-card.component.css']
})
export class AppCardComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input('pro') pro : any;
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
```

in the parent component :

```
<div class="row">
          <div class="col-12 text-center pt-4 mb-4">
            <h3>Featured</h3>
            <hr class="title-border" />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div *ngFor="let pro of cc" class="col-xl-6 p-md-1 p-lg-1 p-xl-2">
            <app-card [pro]="pro" ></app-card>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: By the way, just an fyi, you only need to explicitly specify the 'alias name' of the property within the paranthesis when they are different from what's used within the component. So this, `@Input('pro') pro : any;` could be like this: `@Input() pro : any;`.

Comment: yes i know bro :) , i wrote it in that way , so he can know that the name of the variable can be different to the name of the input in html , thank you anyway @amal for your reply :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass it as input

And use @input attribute on your child component

Answer (score 0):

You can use transclusion.

Parent html,

```
<div class="row">
          <div class="col-12 text-center pt-4 mb-4">
            <h3>Featured</h3>
            <hr class="title-border" />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div *ngFor="let pro of cc" class="col-xl-6 p-md-1 p-lg-1 p-xl-2">
            <app-card>{{ pro.name }}</app-card>
          </div>
        </div>
```

child html,

```
<mat-card class="pt-3">
  <mat-card-header class="text-truncate pb-2">
    <img mat-card-avatar src="http://material.angular.io/assets/img/examples/shiba1.jpg">
    <mat-card-title class="mt-2">
      <ng-content></ng-content>
    </mat-card-title>
  </mat-card-header>
</mat-card>
```

Or you can go with declaring an `@Input` property as suggested in other answers